# How to echo or vardump product detail on cart page

Tags: magento2

How can i call, 
echo or vardump current product detail on cart page from phtml file.

please someone send code or suitable link for that.

Comment: will be difficult. usually magento objects are too large to dump them. It wouldn't be very helpful output either. I suggest you use a proper debugger like xdebug and dive into the data from your favorite IDE. google will turn up enough results how to set that up for your environment.

Comment: can i echo or vardump just current product that add or show in cart page?

Comment: you can but will likely get an error because the object is too large, you can raise figures but I never even tried that so I can't tell you how high you have set the numbers to make it work with var_dump.

Comment: can i just get all attributes values in cart page ???? from phtml file

Comment: You have to use `xdebug` , As object size big, so you don't use var_dump or zend_debug

Comment: Any updates here? Could you solve your issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For debugging large object you can use `$someDataObject->debug()`. It will leave out all recursive data and keeps your log small.

See: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DataObject.php#L461-L489

Comment: that is good idea. I will try to use it

Answer (score 1):

I think, he is looking for not just **printing data**, but print the **quote items** in cart page. If it is exactly what you're looking for, you can try this:

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme-name}/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart.phtml

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    \Zend_Debug::dump($item->debug());
    //OR
    \Zend_Debug::dump($item->getProductId());
    \Zend_Debug::dump($item->getName());
    \Zend_Debug::dump($item->getSku());
    \Zend_Debug::dump($item->getQty());
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento object is large. Use getData function for return array `var_dump($object->getData())`

You should install xdebug extension for debugging.
And you can use var_dump or `\Zend_Debug::dump()`